# How set in WordPress thumbnail php

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I want to connect post with an image, but it doesn't work.
The code that I have tried to use:

```
$my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => $movies->names->cs,
          'post_content'  => "<p>".$movies->plot."</p>",
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => 1,
        );
        $postik =   wp_insert_post( $my_post );#<-- there i add post

        $img = array(
          'post_title'    => $postik,
          'post_content'  => "",
          'post_status'   => 'inherit',
          'post_parent'   => "$postik",
          'guid'   => $movies->poster_url,
          'post_type'   => 'attachment',
          'post_mime_type'   => 'image/jpeg',     
          'post_author'   => 1,
        );
        wp_insert_post( $img ); # <-- there i add image with URL

        set_post_thumbnail( $postik, $img );#<-- there i connect post with thumb
```

But on post is image not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code $img is the array with arguments you use in `wp_insert_post( $img );`.

You're currently using this as the second argument of `set_post_thumbnail()` which is not right.

Instead use:

```
$thumbnail_id = wp_insert_post( $img ); // $thumbnail_id now holds the ID of the inserted image

set_post_thumbnail( $postik, $thumbnail_id ); // Add the thumbnail (ID) to the post
```

Comment: Yeah, i forgot id.. Thanks but it doesn't work. There is post and http://www.csfd.8u.cz/?p=99 there is image http://www.csfd.8u.cz/?p=100 . When you click to show full image resoltuion, image will load.. Image isn't at my server.

Comment: I think the problem is the external image. First you need to find a way to import the external image properly in Wordpress. Then linking the image with your post with `set_post_thumbnail` will work the way it should.

Comment: Thank you very much! I use code from http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-featured-image-url/ and now it's work! Thank